# Why is it illegal to wrap a type with parenthesis when calling a static method?

Tags: java, syntax, types

This question is about curiosity, not an actual problem. Can someone explain why the following code results in a compile time error?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        (Long).parseLong("1"); // won't compile
    }
}
```

The error:

```
Test.java:3: error: illegal start of type
                (Long).parseLong("1");
                ^
1 error
```

With an instance it is legal to have parenthesis (though unnecessary here also):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Long aLong = 1L;
        (aLong).parseLong("1");
    }
}
```

This is of course legal also:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Long.parseLong("1");
    }
}
```

Comment: I remember reading your comment about this...

Comment: Because (Long) is casting. You are casting dot accessing method? i mean `(casting).methodName(arg)`? How does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically in languages like Java, an expression can be freely put in parentheses and remain the same expression. But not everything is an expression. A (naked) typename is one of the things that aren't expressions. It can be a part of many kinds of expressions - but alone, it's not a complete one.

Because of this fact, as has been said in the comments, the parser attempts to parse a parenthesized typename as a part of a cast expression instead (specifically, the "type" part `(Long)`). However, the rest of your code can't be parsed as a valid cast expression (because it must be followed by a valid expression that will yield the casted object - which you don't have, because `.parseLong("1")` isn't a valid expression), so the whole thing is rejected.

Answer (score 2):

You are casting when purely using (Long) without an object lvalue. That's why

When you are using . operator in Java you need to use an lvalue:

```
Long myVal = new Long(30);
myVal.someMethod(args);
```

Read about the subclasses of Java Numbers [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html). You also have to understand how the dot `.` operator works for functions and variables. I think you will find it easier once you get those things correct.

Comment: it this `(Long).parseLong("1"); ` typcasting ? even if lvalue object is there it will not compile

Comment: Think about what you're doing. You are using `.` operator. You need a valid lvalue to use `.` operator. Simply using `Long` ain't gonna cut it. In java `long` is prim type, `Long` is custom type of `long`. In IDEs like Eclipse/NetBeans, you'll see as soon as you type `Long` it becomes highlighted/bold texted or somth. different that usual code. Read about Java Prim Types - 8 of 'em - [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). Also, you need to understand why they did `String`,'Long`,`Int`, etc. additional types on top of prims